# Product variant do not have metafields in theme

Tags: shopify, product, liquid

I am trying to figure out on how to get product variant metafields.

Here is the code which i use to test it. I have put the code into ***product.liquid*** theme file

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var variants = {};
    {% for variant in product.variants %}
      variants[{{variant.id}}] = {{ variant.metafields | json }};
    {% endfor %}

    console.log("VARIANTS", variants);
</script>
```

In the output i do not have metafields data. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `json` filter by referencing the namespace of the metafields that you would like to render. For example if your metafields are in the `global` namespace:

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
  {{ variant.metafields.global | json }}
{% endfor %}
```

More on metafield namespaces here: https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/metafield

Comment: Thanks, but do not understand how it can helps me ). Product variants do not not have metafields properties at all inside theme files. But in database they are exists.

Comment: Hm,seems like everything is ok ). I have put incorrect namespace for the metafields. Thanks for the help!